# Remove wrongly placed tag from post

Tags: discussion

If a question has a tag that has more than one meaning, is it okay to remove the tag if the question does not fulfill the tag's intended meaning?

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8396543/is-it-possible-to-import-some-gml-into-sql-server-2008) is an example of a question that is wrongfully tagged as [gml], but should be [gml-geographic-markup-lan].

Answer (score 1):

If the tag is a poor fit for the question, it should be removed.

However, if it's not your own question (so you have to *suggest* an edit), see what else can be improved about the question. Suggested edits should strive to improve as much as possible, in the suggestion.

Comment: Yeah, I see. I think it would be good idea if we could make tag edits to questions.

Comment: You can, once you get 2k rep. When you suggest a normal edit, you should also be able to edit tags, if I recall correctly.